# Exponentiation of complex numbers and the absolute value

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to find all $w\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that the equation $|w^z|=|w|^z$ holds.

A first result is, that this is true for $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ by repeated multiplication.

For further results I've tried to write both expressions $|w^z|,|w|^z$ as in terms of the $\exp$ function and find some relations in the argument. Somehow I struggle to get the desired results here.

I would appreciate any hints!

Comment: Hints: $w^z=e^{z\log(w)}$, $|e^{x+iy}=e^x$.

Comment: Suppose $z=x+iy$ and $\varphi = arg(w)$ I would end up with $|w^z| = \exp(x\ln |w| -y(\varphi +2k\pi))$ where k is an integer. Right?